# Dev Demon - Forum Subscribe

Tags: devdemon

Having so much trouble with this plugin, no notifcation emails being sent, also when i subscribe or unsubscribe to a forum i get the following.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Functions::remove_double_slashes() in /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/system/expressionengine/third_party/forum_subscribe/mod.forum_subscribe.php on line 315
```

Using MSM and EE version 2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. I believe the function call should be:

```
reduce_double_slashes()
```

not:

```
remove_double_slashes()
```

I couldn't find a `remove_double_slashes` in the function library, but found a `reduce_double_slashes` inside of the CI `string_helper` library.

This sort of thing is usually:

A) A faulty installation of the addon (a file didn't get uploaded, etc). But this doesn't seem likely since it is calling an EE core function, not one within the addon's codebase.

B) Incompatible version of the addon and EE. This seems most likely in this case.

Have you reached out to devdemon with these concerns?

**Edit**

Yup, that function has been deprecated since EE 2.6. Reference:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/functions.html#remove-double-slashes

Devdemon needs to get their codebase updated. You can possibly manually update that function call, but there's probably a bunch of other deprecated function calls too; you paid for it, right? They should fix their shit.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply! Yes i have a feeling that the latest version of this add on is not supported with EE 2.9.0, I am having other issues like the ACT URL sending me to a blank page also. I have uninstalled and re-installed a couple times incase, but still get same problem. I have tried contacting them via a few different methods with no response!

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Thought it was something wrong my end. Yeh i have just purchased it! Sucks because I cant submit a ticket either!

Comment: Keep hitting them up. It's either that or hack the base your self (insane with a purchased product). Mind clicking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Our DB is updated every hour with purchases for support if you buy them on Devot-ee. If you contact us we will provide you an updated version. Thanks!

Comment: Parscale, i have tried contacting dev demon a few times but with no response. Is there a reason that forum subscribe only shows board_id 1?

Comment: We have replied twice to your ticket now. You have never responded. Did you look in your spam box?

Comment: Thanks I have replied now, board="1" parameter does not work. When using that parameter with any number, nothing gets pulled through even though I have boards with ID's 1 and 3.